# How to query metrics stored in azure WADMETRICS table?

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

Using [Extended metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management/azure-vm-extended-metrics#enable-extended-metrics-in-the-azure-portal) I am trying to retrieve certain metrics for certain VMS. Every query seems to take extremely long, as new records are made for each VM every 15 seconds in the table.

So I'm trying to query the table in the last 5 minutes, but it's not working and giving me an error. Does anyone know how to query these WADMETRICS tables?

My code.

```
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectionString);
        CloudTableClient cloudTableClient = account.createCloudTableClient();
        DateTime fiveMinutesAgo = DateTime.now().minusMinutes(5);
        String queryString = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition("Timestamp", TableQuery.QueryComparisons.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, fiveMinutesAgo.toString());
        TableQuery<TableServiceEntity> query = TableQuery.from(TableServiceEntity.class).where(queryString);

        CloudTable table = cloudTableClient.getTableReference("WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20191017");
        System.out.println(table.exists());
        System.out.println(table.getName());
        for (TableServiceEntity entity : table.execute(query)) {
            System.out.println(entity.getPartitionKey() + "\t" + entity.getRowKey());
        }
```

What I get back when I run this.

> An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:113)
>       at com.optum.oea.workbench.service.RemoteAzureService.getVmMetric(RemoteAzureService.java:138)
>       at com.optum.oea.workbench.service.RemoteAzureService.getVmMetric(RemoteAzureService.java:120)
>       at com.optum.oea.workbench.controller.MetricsController.getMetric(MetricsController.java:75)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at com.optum.oea.workbench.config.WorkbenchAttestationFilter.doFilterInternal(WorkbenchAttestationFilter.java:33)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at com.optum.oea.workbench.config.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:65)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceException: Bad Request
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableServiceException.generateTableServiceException(TableServiceException.java:52)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTableClient$2.preProcessResponse(CloudTableClient.java:415)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.CloudTableClient$2.preProcessResponse(CloudTableClient.java:390)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:138)
>       at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySegmentedIterator.java:109)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to query [the WADMETRICS tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-template) by filtering timetap, please refer to the following code:

```
 CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse("connection string");
        CloudTableClient client = account.createCloudTableClient();

        CloudTable table = client.getTableReference("WADMetricsPT1MP10DV2S20191017");
        System.out.println(table.exists());
        System.out.println(table.getName());





        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -19);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,-21);
        Date date = cal.getTime();
//        SimpleDateFormat df = new  SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'");
//        date = df.parse(df.format(date));
//
        System.out.println(date.toString());



        String queryString = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition("Timestamp",TableQuery.QueryComparisons.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, date);

        TableQuery<TableServiceEntity> query = TableQuery.from(TableServiceEntity.class).where(queryString);
        Iterable<TableServiceEntity> results = table.execute(query);
        int i=0;
        for (TableServiceEntity  entity:results
             ) {
            i +=1;
            System.out.println(entity.getPartitionKey());
        }

        System.out.println(i);
```

[image]

Besides, you also can query you Azure  table on the portal:
[image]